# Principals of type Application cannot validly be used in role assignments

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying a new App Registration via Terraform and then assigning a Role in my Event Hub to that App Registration.

E.G.
Deploy App Registration

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "eventhub_auth" {
  display_name = "AppReg"
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMyOrg"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

    app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User", "Application"]
    description          = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "Admin"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = uuid()
    value                = "admin"
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User"]
    description          = "ReadOnly roles have limited query access"
    display_name         = "ReadOnly"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = uuid()
    value                = "User"
  }
}
```

Role Assignment:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "receiver" {
  scope                = resource.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Event Hubs Data Receiver"
  principal_id         = # I have tried the Object_ID, Application_ID and the Tenant_ID here and all of them fail
}
```

Is there another ID/Service Principle somewhere that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work this out. Working config is:

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "eventhub" {
  application_id = azuread_application.eventhub_auth.application_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "receiver" {
  scope                = resource.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Event Hubs Data Receiver"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.eventhub.id
}
```

Answer (score 11):

All applications that get registered in AzureAD (EntraID), in the tenant, two types of objects get created once the app registration is done.

- An Application Object:  The **Application Object** is what you see under App Registrations in Azure active directory blade. Along with Client Secret, this one is used for *authentication*. E.g. `Connect-AzAccount -Credential <Credential PS Object With AppID> -Tenant XXX -ServicePrincipal`
- A Service Principal Object: The **Service Principal Object** is what you see under the Enterprise Registration in Azure active directory blade. This one is used for *authorization*. E.g. `New-AzRoleAssignment  -ObjectId <Object ID from Enterprise App> -RoleDefinitionName XX -Scope XX`

In my case I mistakenly used `object id` from the `App Registration` Screen of AzureAD (EntraID), and got this error.

After using the `object id` from `Enterprise Application` showns on AzureAD (EntraID) screen this error was gone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to run `az ad sp list --filter "displayName eq 'your_service_principal_name'"` and take from the response ID parameter